# How to trace the reason for compilation errors in a pecl zip install operation (with a legacy version of PHP)?

Tags: php, c, centos, php-extension

I have an unavoidable need to develop systems based on PHP 5.4. I am aware that this is well out of security updates, but it is what I have for now. I wish to create a PHP 5.4 Docker image for development purposes. Historically my team and I have been using a PHP 5.6 image based on Centos, since there are no 5.4 Centos images available.

Thus, I am trying to compile PHP 5.4. With a lot of trial and error, I have got it to compile PHP with minimal compiled-in extensions, and then with a bunch of dynamically loadable extensions on top. This means that my various downstream projects can select what extensions they need just by adding the right `php.ini` extension commands.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# A custom Docker/PHP build for 5.4
#
# PHP 5.4 is no longer available as a standard image as it is
# well out of support. Centos has been chosen to mirror live
# servers.

FROM centos:7 AS build

# Do OS updates using fastest mirrors
RUN yum update -y

# Here is the raw OS (give up if repo is down)
RUN timeout 3m yum install -y wget curl gcc make
# Here are some dependencies (give up if repo is down)
RUN timeout 3m yum install -y \
        libxml2-devel libssh-devel \
        openssl-devel curl-devel postgresql-devel \
        autoconf

WORKDIR /root

RUN wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.4.45.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf php-5.4.45.tar.gz

WORKDIR /root/php-5.4.45

# Compile here
# OpenSSL/curl are used nearly everywhere, e.g. Compose
# zlib is useful but not required for Composer
RUN ./configure \
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-openssl-dir \
    --with-curl=/usr/local/bin \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-pdo-mysql
RUN make && make install

# Create a store for the modules
RUN mkdir /root/exts

# Compile some PHP extensions (keep in alpha order please)
RUN cd ext/bcmath    && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/bcmath.so    /root/exts/
RUN yum install -y bzip2-devel
RUN cd ext/bz2       && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/bz2.so       /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/calendar  && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/calendar.so  /root/exts/
RUN yum install -y enchant-devel
RUN cd ext/enchant   && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/enchant.so   /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/exif      && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/exif.so      /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/ftp       && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/ftp.so       /root/exts/
RUN yum install -y libpng-devel
RUN cd ext/gd        && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/gd.so        /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/gettext   && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/gettext.so   /root/exts/
RUN yum install -y gmp-devel
RUN cd ext/gmp       && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/gmp.so       /root/exts/

# Investigate this one
# igbinary

RUN yum install -y libicu-devel gcc-c++
RUN cd ext/intl      && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/intl.so      /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/mbstring  && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/mbstring.so  /root/exts/

# See comments under https://www.mojowill.com/geek/php-mcrypt-on-centos-6/ to
# install "Centos Extras"
RUN yum install epel-release -y && yum update -y
RUN yum install -y libmcrypt-devel
RUN cd ext/mcrypt    && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/mcrypt.so    /root/exts/

# This is not included in the source bundle, so we need to fetch and compile
RUN yum install -y libmemcached-devel zlib-devel autoconf gcc make
RUN pecl install memcached-2.2.0
RUN cp /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so /root/exts/

RUN cd ext/mysql     && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/mysql.so     /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/mysqli    && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/mysqli.so    /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/pcntl     && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/pcntl.so     /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/pdo       && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/pdo.so       /root/exts/

RUN cd ext/pdo_pgsql && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/pdo_pgsql.so /root/exts/
RUN yum install -y libedit-devel readline-devel
RUN cd ext/readline  && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/readline.so  /root/exts/

# Investigate this one
#RUN cd ext/redis     && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/redis.so     /root/exts/

RUN cd ext/shmop     && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/shmop.so     /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/soap      && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/soap.so      /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/sockets   && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/sockets.so   /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/sysvmsg   && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/sysvmsg.so   /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/sysvsem   && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/sysvsem.so   /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/sysvshm   && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/sysvshm.so   /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/wddx      && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/wddx.so      /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/xml       && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/xml.so       /root/exts/
RUN cd ext/xmlrpc    && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/xmlrpc.so    /root/exts/
RUN yum install -y libxslt-devel
RUN cd ext/xsl       && phpize && ./configure && make && cp modules/xsl.so       /root/exts/

# The PECL compile fails, but the version of libzip (0.10.1) looks exactly right
RUN yum install -y libzip-devel gcc
RUN pecl install zip-1.11.0
# Does not compile either on Centos 6 or 7
```

This works completely except for the last piece, which is the pecl installation of the zip extension. Here is my console output (from a Docker step):

```
Step 52/70 : RUN pecl install zip-1.11.0
 ---> Running in 06d2ef53ba56
downloading zip-1.11.0.tgz ...
Starting to download zip-1.11.0.tgz (263,909 bytes)
......................................................done: 263,909 bytes
93 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserhYPzzK/zip-1.11.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for zip archive read/writesupport... yes, shared
checking for the location of libz... no
checking pcre install prefix... no
checking for the location of zlib... /usr
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of off_t... 8
checking size of size_t... 8
checking for touch... /usr/bin/touch
checking for unzip... no
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure: line 6197: /usr/bin/file: No such file or directory
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserhYPzzK/zip-1.11.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserhYPzzK/zip-1.11.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserhYPzzK/zip-1.11.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c -o php_zip.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserhYPzzK/zip-1.11.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserhYPzzK/zip-1.11.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/zip -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_zip.o
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c: In function 'php_zip_get_property_ptr_ptr':
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c:882:3: warning: passing argument 3 of 'std_hnd->get_property_ptr_ptr' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   retval = std_hnd->get_property_ptr_ptr(object, member, type, key TSRMLS_CC);
   ^
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c:882:3: note: expected 'const struct _zend_literal *' but argument is of type 'int'
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c:882:3: error: too many arguments to function 'std_hnd->get_property_ptr_ptr'
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c: In function 'zm_startup_zip':
/tmp/pear/temp/zip/php_zip.c:2759:43: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  zip_object_handlers.get_property_ptr_ptr = php_zip_get_property_ptr_ptr;
                                           ^
make: *** [php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

This is rather an unexpected compilation error - "too many arguments" feels like there is a library mismatch or something, but I have specifically selected 1.11, which is the version of the extension on the production servers. Could it be that my version of `libzip-devel` is too new, and if so, can I obtain an earlier one, and have it work in a maintained version of Centos?

I have not encountered this issue on any other extension, so perhaps it is just bad luck I have a tricker problem on the last one!

### Update

The native version of `libzip-devel` in the version of Centos I am using is 0.10.1, which matches the version of `libzip` that is reported by the production servers (via `php -i`). Here is the info from the Docker image:

```
[root@0b093624d012 /]# yum info libzip-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * extras: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * updates: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
Available Packages
Name        : libzip-devel
Arch        : i686
Version     : 0.10.1
Release     : 8.el7
Size        : 77 k
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : Development files for libzip
URL         : http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html
License     : BSD
Description : The libzip-devel package contains libraries and header files for
            : developing applications that use libzip.

Name        : libzip-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.10.1
Release     : 8.el7
Size        : 77 k
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : Development files for libzip
URL         : http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html
License     : BSD
Description : The libzip-devel package contains libraries and header files for
            : developing applications that use libzip.
```

I doubt that changing my C compiler might help, but I am certainly open to ideas in that direction.

Comment: I assume that `get_property_ptr_ptr` is a library function. You may have multiple versions of libzip, and your compiler chose an unwanted one. You are failing while compiling object files, so check your header files.

Comment: Thanks @BruceShen. I don't think it would not be possible for me to have multiple installations of `libzip-devel`, as I am in Docker, and I assume it is not a default installation of Centos 7.

Comment: The good news though is that I have a fix, which I will write up when I have some free time. I bumped from zip-1.11.0 to zip-1.12.3, which fixed it. It's not completely ideal, since my prod servers really do have PHP 5.4 with zip-1.11.0, but I can't think this minor difference is doing to make much of a difference to the intended development usage of this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this.

In case it is helpful to record what did not work, I first noticed that I had a patch-level PHP version discrepancy. My production server is on 5.4.16, and I was building for 5.4.45. I adjusted that, confident that it would download the correct code to link with other libraries, only to find that it made no difference.

I then analysed how many version numbers I had to bump up in the pecl zip extension to get a next available stable version, which took me from zip-1.11.0 to zip-1.12.3. This compiled fine. It is not ideal, because my production server really does mix zip 1.11.0 with PHP 5.4.16, but no matter - we have been developing using 5.6 for around a year, even though we target 5.4 in production. Thus, the new image is still a substantial win, given that it takes us much closer to our live environment.